# How to get Control Register (CR2) value?

Tags: gdb, x86-64

Do we have a way to find the value of CR2 from core of x86-64 ?
Info registers doesn't show it.

```
(gdb) info registers  all
rax            0x7fc9ca854000   140504662884352
rbx            0x119ad58        18459992
rcx            0xa0000  655360
rdx            0x7fca99045300   140508127318784
rsi            0x1      1
rdi            0x120    288
rbp            0x7fc9d0104e40   0x7fc9d0104e40
rsp            0x7fc9d0104c70   0x7fc9d0104c70
r8             0x0      0
r9             0xc0     192
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x7fca1432b2e0   140505898988256
r12            0x7fc9c95e5d80   140504643558784
r13            0x800a0003       2148139011
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x7fc94537d198   140502426440088
rip            0x666831 0x666831 
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
st0            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st1            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st2            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st3            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st4            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st5            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st6            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
st7            0        (raw 0x00000000000000000000)
fctrl          0x37f    895
fstat          0x0      0
ftag           0xffff   65535
fiseg          0x0      0
fioff          0x0      0
foseg          0x0      0
fooff          0x0      0
fop            0x0      0
xmm0           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm1           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm2           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x21, 0x80, 0x0 <repeats 14 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x8021, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x8021, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x8021, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000008021
}
xmm3           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0xa8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x58, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0xa8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x58, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0xa8, 0x0, 0x58, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0xa8, 0x58},
  uint128 = 0x000000000000005800000000000000a8
}
xmm4           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm5           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x92, 0xff, 0x0 <repeats 14 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0xff92, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000ff92
}
xmm6           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0xf8, 0x51, 0x0, 0x0, 0x33, 0xcc, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc9, 0x7f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0x51f8, 0x0, 0xcc33, 0x0, 0x7fc9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x51f8, 0xcc33, 0x7fc9, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0xcc33000051f8, 0x7fc9},
  uint128 = 0x0000000000007fc90000cc33000051f8
}
xmm7           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm8           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm9           {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0xe8, 0x3b, 0x3, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x97, 0x2, 0x0, 0x92, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0x3be8, 0x3, 0x97f8, 0x2, 0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x33be8, 0x297f8, 0xff92, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x297f800033be8, 0xff92},
  uint128 = 0x000000000000ff92000297f800033be8
}
xmm10          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x82, 0xa3, 0x1, 0x0, 0x66, 0x98, 0x1, 0x0, 0x92, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0xa382, 0x1, 0x9866, 0x1, 0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x1a382, 0x19866, 0xff92, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x198660001a382, 0xff92},
  uint128 = 0x000000000000ff92000198660001a382
}
xmm11          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x92, 0xff, 0x0 <repeats 14 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0xff92, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x0000000000000000000000000000ff92
}
xmm12          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0xf8, 0x51, 0x0, 0x0, 0x33, 0xcc, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc9, 0x7f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0x51f8, 0x0, 0xcc33, 0x0, 0x7fc9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x51f8, 0xcc33, 0x7fc9, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0xcc33000051f8, 0x7fc9},
  uint128 = 0x0000000000007fc90000cc33000051f8
}
xmm13          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x0 <repeats 16 times>},
  v8_int16 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x0, 0x0},
  uint128 = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
}
xmm14          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0xe8, 0x3b, 0x3, 0x0, 0xf8, 0x97, 0x2, 0x0, 0x92, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0x3be8, 0x3, 0x97f8, 0x2, 0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x33be8, 0x297f8, 0xff92, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x297f800033be8, 0xff92},
  uint128 = 0x000000000000ff92000297f800033be8
}
xmm15          {
  v4_float = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v2_double = {0x0, 0x0},
  v16_int8 = {0x82, 0xa3, 0x1, 0x0, 0x66, 0x98, 0x1, 0x0, 0x92, 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v8_int16 = {0xa382, 0x1, 0x9866, 0x1, 0xff92, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0},
  v4_int32 = {0x1a382, 0x19866, 0xff92, 0x0},
  v2_int64 = {0x198660001a382, 0xff92},
  uint128 = 0x000000000000ff92000198660001a382
}
mxcsr          0x1f80   [ IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Intel's instruction set manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) page 3-514 "MOV — Move to/from Control Registers".

> This instruction can be executed only when the current privilege level is 0.

As GDB is a ring 3 process, it can't read `cr2` and any other control register.

Of course, process core dumps wouldn't have control registers because these registers are not part of task state.

Comment: GDB reads registers using a `ptrace` system call, because it wants the state of the target process, not itself.  So the key point is that `cr2` isn't part of the process state, it's a mechanism for the OS to find the page-fault address.  GDB itself running in ring 3 is irrelevant because it reads target registers via the kernel (ring 0).

Answer (score 2):

If your have a core dump file and this file is triggered by SIGSEGV or SIGBUS.
Use **p $_siginfo** and find _sigfault and si_addr. si_addr should be the same as cr2 in this scenario.

For example,

```
$5 = {si_signo = 7, si_errno = 0, si_code = 2, ...  _sigfault = {si_addr = 0x7ff6205bee64, ... }
```

Hope this will be helpful.